# Read a Json File. Add an additional field depending on one of the field values. Write back Json

Tags: java, json

I have a json file that looks like

```
[{"field1":Value1, 
  "field2":value2,
     "field3_find":[value3,value4],
      "field4_find":{"sub1":subval1,"sub2":subvalue2}
   }

{"field1":Value5,
    "field2":value6,
     "field3_find":[value7,value8],
      "field4_find":{"sub1":subval3,"sub2":subvalue3}
   }
]
```

I want to read the Json. Find a particular key value pair. Once a matching field is found , create a new field depending on the value of this field. Write back Json.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.FileReader;
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap< String, JSONObject>> AllRows;
AllRows = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(InputFile));  
JSONArray New_rows =new JSONArray(); 
LinkedList<String> FieldNameAnotation=new LinkedList<String>();
         FieldNameAnotation.add(new String("field3_find"));
         FieldNameAnotation.add(new String("field4_find"));

        try {
            for(LinkedHashMap<String,JSONObject> map : AllRows){
                JSONObject  extend_row=new JSONObject();  
                for (Map.Entry<String, JSONObject> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if ((FieldNameAnotation).contains(entry.getKey()))
                    {
                    newvalue1=process1(entry.getKey());
                     newvalue2=process2(entry.getKey());// call a function process to get this value
                        extend_row.put(newvalue1,newvalue2);
                    } 
                }
                extend_row.putAll(map);
                New_rows.add(extend_row);  
           }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

However this gives an error
 org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap.

I know that it is because the way I have read the JSON .It is read as an array of JSON objects, But I do not how to read it as

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap< String, JSONObject>>
```

Comment: Don't use leading upper case for variable names.

Comment: Read and manipulate the data entirely in JSONObjects and JSONArrays, vs using ArrayLists and HashMaps.  List and Maps are good in theory but Java generics make them unmanageable.

Comment: If I use JSONArrays like       JSONArray AllRows                then how do I access key value pairs for each record of the array. when I use it like                                       for(JSONObject map : AllRows){},                                     it again gives an error           Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to JSONObject